# Connecting an Xbox 360 controller to Windows 10 with a wireless receiver with no sync button

Tags: pc, xbox-360, controllers, windows-10, windows

I have a generic wireless receiver which I have set up as an Xbox 360 wireless receiver using the microsoft official drivers, but the device does not have a sync button. It does have a button but it was originally for a different purpose. Is it possible to force the syncing process to begin using software instead of the physical button?

Comment: I've never seen a knockoff Xbox 360 receiver that didn't have the sync button. Can you link to a product page or something? Sorry, I don't know how to initiate sync without the button. (Are you sure the "different purpose" button isn't the one you want?)

Answer (score 0):

The xbox 360 controller is not supported for other devices without a driver, but you can use a dual USB output cable by connecting the controller to the PC and downloading a controller mapper.